# add custom image to bottom of wordpress default login screen

Tags: css, wp-login-form

Is it possible to somehow via functions.php to add an extra image on the bottom of the default wordpress login page?

Obs! - not the logo,  this would be an extra image, below the "normal" login form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [the `login_footer` action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_footer/) to add code before the closing `</body>` tag (untested):

```php
add_action( 'login_footer', static function () {
   echo '<img src="..." />';
} );
```

Comment: It worked fine, but is it possible to center the location of the image

Comment: Yep. Use CSS to do that.